# Multiple PIM Profiles

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

Is it possible to have multiple profiles for a PIM role within Azure? If not, is this something that is on the roadmap?

Question from customer: "as you know you can customize the roles to specify the window for that privilege, the approvers and so on. Could you have multiple profiles for each role in the future?"

Comment: It seems not support multiple profiles for PIM role. You could feedback to [Azure UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the privileged access groups feature. Simply create two groups, apply different policies and make the users eligible for the group (do not assign the group as eligible, since the members are eligible for the group, which would require them to activate twice). Documentation can be found at aka.ms/pag

Comment: Nothing prevents customers from using these privileged groups for other scenarios outside of role assignment. The only consideration is if an eligible member of the group needs their password reset (i.e. cannot complete SSPR on their own), a GA or PRA would have to reset that password. Helpdesk admins and user admins can’t reset the user’s password since the user is a member of a privileged group (preventing the possibility of privileged account escalation). This is a consideration the customer should make, but as I mentioned, nothing prevents them from using these groups for other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve, but what I can see it's only for Azure AD roles, right? It's not possible to assign Azure resources.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new privileged access group you can only assign Azure AD roles but not Azure resources roles during the creation, that's what I meant... because with that you can modify the properties for that specific role, in terms of time of the privileged mode, who are the approvers, and so on... will it be available in the future?

Do we know when will it be in GA?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ignore assigning roles at group creation time. Simply create the role and enable it for role assignment (this part is required if you want to use it with PIM). Once it's created (even with no AAD roles assigned to it) you can enable the group for Privileged access. After enabling the group for privileged access you can assign members as Eligible, and configure assignment and activation settings for the member and/or owner roles. ETA for GA of this feature (privileged access groups) is end of the calendar year.